# Azure Data Catalog Gen2 is free?

Tags: azure, azure-data-catalog

Nowadays im using Azure Data Catalog Gen1

I saw that Azure Data Catalog Gen2 is in preview...

If i create a gen2, the cost is free?

Thanks

Comment: where did you see ADC Gen2 mentioned? I cannot find any reference to it anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Previews are at no cost.  PREVIEWS ARE PROVIDED "AS-IS," "WITH ALL FAULTS," AND "AS AVAILABLE," AND ARE EXCLUDED FROM THE SERVICE LEVEL AGREEMENTS AND LIMITED WARRANTY. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/preview-supplemental-terms/